# Run script when systemd service fails

Tags: linux, command-line, services, systemd

I'm running Debian 8 on a server.

How do I run a bash script if a `systemd`  controlled service fails to start or restart?

Similarly if a service suddenly stops and cannot continue. In effect I want to run a script no matter how the service fails.

Comment: duplicate: [Run an arbitrary command when a service fails](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/197636/44425)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't comment but...

Have you tried using [`OnFailure=`](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#OnFailure=) in the `[Unit]` section?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Anyway I can test it easily m